# UIButton animation view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am new developer in iPhone.

I want to create uibutton.

When I click the button, then the button will be flash like as below.

[image]

How to create the flash, when I click my button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a property of UIButton named *showsTouchWhenHighlighted*. If you set the property to YES, it will show the glow when you touch the button. It's default value is NO.

> [yourButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];

Answer (score 0):

What you do is set the highlighted image. For example:

```
[someButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MyHighlight.png"] 
            forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Then when a user taps it, your `MyHighlight.png` will show.

Answer (score 0):

```
toolbar = [UIToolbar new];
 toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
 [toolbar sizeToFit];
 toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 410, 320, 50);

 //Add buttons
 UIBarButtonItem *systemItem1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                     target:self
                     action:@selector(pressButton1:)];

 UIBarButtonItem *systemItem2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction
                     target:self
                     action:@selector(pressButton2:)];

 UIBarButtonItem *systemItem3 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
         initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera
         target:self action:@selector(pressButton3:)];

 //Use this to put space in between your toolbox buttons
 UIBarButtonItem *flexItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                     target:nil
                     action:nil];

 //Add buttons to the array
 NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: systemItem1, flexItem, systemItem2, flexItem, systemItem3, nil];

 //release buttons
 [systemItem1 release];
 [systemItem2 release];
 [systemItem3 release];
 [flexItem release];

 //add array of buttons to toolbar
 [toolbar setItems:items animated:NO];

 [self.view addSubview:toolbar];
```

use this to create toolBar.

and use this for search button

```
UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the button image when you clicked on button now set different images for both default and highlighted stats. As:

```
[tempButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NormalImage.png"] 
            forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[tempButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"HighlightImage.png"] 
            forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

If you want the flash effect for the same image, when button is clicked on,
In your XIB, Goto Inspector window > control > check the Highlighted property.
You can try this by code as:

```
 [tempButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];

//or
tempButton.highlighted = YES;
```